# Can Windows 10 running as a VM on Ubuntu make optimal use of the graphics card?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware, gaming

I have a Lenovo IP 320E with the configuration:

> Intel Core i5 7th generation processor
>
> 8 GB RAM
>
> NVIDIA GeForce 940MX Graphics Card

Ubuntu 17.04 is my host OS and I want to keep it that way. However, I want to install Windows 10 as a guest VM on it, with the intention of playing games. What settings should I configure so that the Windows system can make the best use of the GPU? Does the choice of VM client i.e. VMware/Virtualbox make any difference?

Comment: For VirtualBox, has a look through the [display settings section](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display) in the manual. Video memory size, 3D Acceleration and 2D Acceleration are the most important settings here.

Comment: i've deleted my answer because i just noticed you're asking for a laptop. pci passthrough for laptops isn't a viable option afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You must use GPU pass-through.
Requirement: your card must be on the [compatibility list](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=vsga)

- Using the vSphere Client, you must connect to VMware vCenter and select the host with the GPU card installed.
- In the *Configuration* tab for the host, and click *Advanced Settings*
- To configure passthrough for the GPU, click *Configure Passthrough*.
- In the *Mark Devices* for *Passthrough window*, check the box that corresponds to the GPU adapter installed in the VM host.
- After clicking OK, the GPU should be listed now in the Window on the *Advanced settings* page.
- Make sure the Hardware VM is updated to Version 9+
- For GPU passthrough to function, all the VM configured memory must be reserved. (To update this, select the *Reserve all guest memory* option when you view the *Memory options* under the *Resources tab* in the VM's settings window. For virtual machines that have more than 2GB of configured memory, add the following parameter to the .vmx file of the virtual machine (you can add this at the end of the file): `pciHole.start = “2048”`)
- Using the vSphere Client, connect directly to the ESXi host with the GPU card installed, or select the host in vCenter.
- Right-click the virtual machine and select *Edit Settings* and add a new device by selecting PCI Device from the list, and click *Next*.
- Select the GPU as the passthrough device to connect to the virtual machine from the drop-down list, and click *Next*, *Finish*.
- Install latest OS drivers and reboot the VM.

[Deployment guide](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmware-horizon-view-graphics-acceleration-deployment.pdf)

Now the GPU is directly allocated to the W10 VM and you should benefit from it's performance.